# C++ safeguards exceeding limits of integer

Tags: c++, integer

I am working on a chapter review of a book: at the end of the chapter there are some questions/tasks which you are to complete.

I decided to do them in the format of a program rather than a text file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::cout << "Chapter review\n"
    << "1. Why does C++ have more than one integer type?\n"
        << "\tTo be able to represent more accurate values & save memory by only allocating what is needed for the task at hand.\n"

    << "2. Declare variables matching the following descriptions:\n"
        << "a.\tA short integer with the value 80:\n";
            short myVal1 = 80;
std::cout << "\t\t\"short myVal1 = 80;\": " << myVal1 << std::endl

        << "b.\tAn unsigned int integer with the value 42,110:\n";
            unsigned int myVal2 = 42110;
std::cout << "\t\t\"unsigned int myVal2 = 42110;\": " << myVal2 << std::endl

        << "c.\tAn integer with the value 3,000,000,000:\n";
            float myVal3 = 3E+9;
std::cout << "\t\t\"float myVal3 = 3E+9;\": " << static_cast<unsigned int>(myVal3) << std::endl

    << "3. What safeguards does C++ provide to keep you from exceeding the limits of an integer type?\n"
        << "\tWhen it reaches maximum number it starts from the begging again (lowest point).\n"

    << "4. What is the distinction between 33L and 33?\n"
            << "\t33L is of type long, 33 is of type int.\n"

    << "5. Consider the two C++ statements that follow:\n\tchar grade = 65;\n\tchar grade = 'A';\nAre they equivalent?\n"
            << "\tYes, the ASCII decimal number for 'A' is '65'.\n"

    << "6. How could you use C++ to find out which character the code 88 represents?\nCome up with at least two ways.\n"
            << "\t1: \"static_cast<char>(88);\": " << static_cast<char>(88) << std::endl; // 1.
            char myChar = 88;
std::cout   << "\t2: \"char myChar = 88;\": " << myChar << std::endl // 2.
            << "\t3: \"std::cout << (char) 88;\"  " << (char) 88 << std::endl // 3.
            << "\t4: \"std::cout << char (88);\": " << char (88) << std::endl // 4.

    << "7. Assigning a long value to a float can result in a rounding error. What about assigning long to double? long long to double?\n"
            << "\tlong -> double: Rounding error.\n\tlong long -> double: Significantly incorrect number and/or rounding error.\n"

    << "8. Evaluate the following expressions as C++ would:\n"
        << "a.\t8 * 9 + 2\n"
            << "\t\tMultiplication (8 * 9 = 72) -> addition (72 + 2 = 74).\n"
        << "b.\t6 * 3 / 4\n"
            << "\t\tMultiplication (6 * 3 = 18 -> division (18 / 4 = 4).\n"
        << "c.\t3 / 4 * 6\n"
            << "\t\tDivision (3 / 4 = 0) -> multiplication (0 * 6 = 0).\n"
        << "d.\t6.0 * 3 / 4\n"
            << "\t\tMultiplication (6.0 * 3 -> 18.0) -> division (18.0 / 4 = 4.5).\n"
        << "e.\t 15 % 4\n"
            << "\t\tDivision (15 / 4 = 3.75) Then returns the reminder, basically how many times can 4 go into 15 in this case that is 3 (3*4 = 12).\n"

    << "9. Suppose x1 and x2 are two type of double variables that you want to add as integers and assign to an integer variable. Construct a C++ statement for doing so. What if you wanted to add them as type double and then convert to int?\n"
        << "\t1: \"int myInt = static_cast<double>(doubleVar);\"\n\t2: \"int myInt = int (doubleVar);\".\n"

    << "10. What is the variable type for each of the following declarations?\n"
        << "a.\t\"auto cars = 15;\"\n\t\tint\n"
        << "b.\t\"auto iou = 150.37f;\"\n\t\tfloat\n"
        << "c.\t\"auto level = 'B';\"\n\t\tchar\n"
        << "d.\t\"auto crat = U'/U00002155';\"\n\t\twchar_t ?\n"
        << "e.\t\"auto fract = 8.25f/.25;\"\n\t\tfloat" << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

It's been a while since I read chapter 3 due to moving/some other real life stuff.

What I am unsure about here is basically question number 3: it says safeguards as in plural.

However I am only aware of one: that it starts from the beginning again after reaching maximum value? Am I missing something here?

Let me know if you see any other errors also - I am doing this to learn after all :).

Comment: excellent to see you are self-learning... by actually doing...

Comment: This is not a safeguard. Silently ignoring an error and doing something silly, like rolling over, instead of raising a proper error, is not safe and guards you from nothing. The correct answer to this question is **none**.

Comment: (continued) Consider this dialogue. Q: What safeguards do you have in place to prevent visitors from walking over the edge of the roof? A: Gravity. Anybody attempting to walk over the edge would not succeed in doing so, they will fall to their death instead, thanks to gravity. Mission accomplished: no one walks beyond the edge of the roof! Do you agree?

Comment: **10.e** : `8.25f/.25`, type is `double` (as `.25`) not `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I can't accept a comment as an answer so to sum it up:

There are none safeguards, I misunderstood that question which @n.m. clarified for me.

10.e was wrong as pointed out by @Jarod42, which is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for me "Declare variable of integer with the value 3,000,000,000" is:

```
    unsigned anInteger = 3000000000;
```

cause c++ the 11th supplies 15 integer types and unsigned int is the smallest that can store such a big integer as 3 000 000 000.

Answer (score 0):

C++ classifies integer overflow as "Undefined Behavior" - anything can happen as a result of it. This by itself may be called a "safeguard" (though it's a stretch), by the following thinking:

gcc has that `-ftrapv` compilation switch that makes your program crash when integer overflow happens. This allows you to debug your overflows easily. This feature is possible because C++ made it legal (by nature of Undefined Behavior) to make your program crash in these circumstances. I think the C++ Committee had this exact scenario in mind when making that part of the C++ Standard.

This is different from e.g. Java, where integer overflow causes wraparound, and is probably harder to debug.